# I can't inject two or more class on my service provider

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I am currently implementing repository pattern and dependency injection on my laravel project. But when I inject two or more class, I got this error

`Too few arguments to function App\Repositories\UserRepository::__construct(), 0 passed`

I don't know what's wrong but I think I did it correctly. Here's my code:

My service provider:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(LoanRepository::class, function() {
       return new LoanRepository(new Loan, new UserRepository);
    });
}
```

and here's my Repository

```
public function __construct($loan, $userRepository)
{
    $this->loan = $loan;
    $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
}
```

does anyone experience this?

Comment: you need to pass the arguments needed to the constructor of your `UserRepository` when you are 'new'ing it, or you would need to use the container to resolve an instance of it for you (assuming it could resolve the dependencies for `UserRepository` automatically or you would then need a binding for that as well)

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the UserRepository class is expecting some arguments that you are not passing it. Below would be an example of how you would pass a constructor argument to your `new UserRepositiry` call.

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(LoanRepository::class, function() {
        return new LoanRepository(new Loan, new UserRepository($constructorArgsHere);
    });
}
```

I haven't worked with Laravel so I don't know what the UserRepository class constructor is looking for as arguments, but that should be an easy thing to find out just looking at the file where that class is defined or a quick google search.